# Return trigger before refresh concurrently on materialized view is finished

Tags: postgresql, triggers, materialized-views

I have a database where data from different source tables are processed and stored in a materialized view.
I choosed to store it as a MV because the query to process this data takes a while - about 3 seconds - and needs to be called all the time.

So, I created a trigger to refresh the MV every time the source table is modified (INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE).

The problem is, it seems the trigger function waits for the materialized view to finish refreshing to return, and I don't want this.

I want the insert operation to return as fast as possible, and the MV to refresh in parallel.

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "MOBILIDADE".atualizar_mv_solicitacao()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY "MOBILIDADE"."MV_SOLICITACAO";
RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER solicitacao_atualizar_mv_solicitacao
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON "MOBILIDADE"."GESTAOPROJETOS_SOLICITACAO"
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "MOBILIDADE".atualizar_mv_solicitacao();
```

When I run an INSERT operation with the trigger function enabled, it takes about 3 seconds to finish, while when I execute it with the trigger disabled it takes only seconds 0.07 seconds.

```
INSERT INTO "MOBILIDADE"."GESTAOPROJETOS_SOLICITACAO" (documento_tipo,documento_numero,documento_sigla,documento_ano,requerente,solicitacao,data,data_recebimento_semob,categorias,geom,endereco_regiao,endereco_bairro,endereco_logradouro,anexo,created_by,created_at,acao) VALUES('Indicação',12345,'TESTE',2022,'TESTE','TESTE','2022-09-15','2022-09-15','{"Barreiras físicas" , "Pavimentação"}',ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-45.888675631640105,-23.236909838714148),4326),4326),'Sul','Bosque dos Eucaliptos','Rua Lima Duarte',false,1,NOW(),1) RETURNING id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to go about it. If refreshing the materialized view takes long and you modify the table often, then you cannot refresh the materialized view on every data change. Even if the refresh runs asynchronously (which is not possible with a trigger), it will still put a lot of load on your system.

Consider alternative solutions:

- Refresh the materialized view every five minutes or so.
- Don't use a materialized view, but a regular table that contains the aggregates and update that table from a trigger whenever the underlying data change. That will only work if the "materialized view" is simple enough.

Comment: Operations on the tables occur constantly, but at a much lower frequency than the need to read the data. We're talking about 200 INSERT/UPDATE operations a day, while SELECT occurs all the time. 
A 3 seconds refresh after all operations would not overload to the system.

I can't figure how aggregate all data on the main table, virtual columns is quite limited and my process depends on such complicate recursive operations on a second table of events - the process the MV is doing.
Recurrent refresh is what I'm thinking as my last alternative, if I can't find a way of asynchronously trigger.

Comment: There is no asynchronous trigger. You'd have to either solve this on the application side or use `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` in PostgreSQL and a worker that listens for requests.

Comment: it's sad it's not possible async trigger, it seems to be a feature that can be useful in different occasions in a database.

Thanks for the support, I will study best ways to call the refresh by the application every time I run a data modification query.